# Jquery event which triggers whenever window.location.href gets altered

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way I can trigger an event whenever I alter window.location.href using jQuery?

I am using **onbeforeunload** but that triggers only if it is a **navigation to a new url**. For me the event need to be triggered even if I am altering the location.href by appending "&key" to it.

Comment: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=_2eJYbM5vycC&pg=RA1-PA43&lpg=RA1-PA43&dq=window.location.watch&source=bl&ots=ZNU1AeyNO4&sig=0SUHLw8KatBj6K1a5046x9UhHYw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj60_nH_qfRAhUM0YMKHZS3Ax0Q6AEIRzAG#v=onepage&q=window.location.watch&f=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.location.watch
```

you can use above for your need

for further reading https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1520-binding-events-to-non-dom-objects-with-jquery.htm

Comment: Can you please explain how to make use of window.location.watch ?